# Deployment using ssh with key without providing passphrase for private key (ssh-agent)

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, laravel, ssh-agent

**Wherein lies the difference between Capistrano and Rocketeer when it comes to the passphrase for a private key?**

I already have both Capistrano and Rocketeer deployment strategies set up properly and working. Capistrano lets **ssh-agent provide the passphrase** - Rocketeer, as it seems, does not. The question is not about how but why the passphrase is needed.

*Background:*

I want to use [Rocketeer](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/rocketeer) for deployment of a Laravel application instead of Capistrano. It seems as if it delegates the SSH connection to Laravel.

After setting only the remote server's name in the configuration and running a check, after some prompts for credentials Rocketeer stores the needed passphrase and the path to my desired private key in a non-version-controlled file.

I do not want to have credentials for establishing a SSH connection stored on my disk - especially **not** the passphrase to any of my private keys.

So, why is anything more than the server's name required?

I see that Laravel has those fields prepared in its remotes config - I just could not find out which component is responsible eventually and why it does not leave the SSH connection completely to the system itself.

Is it **Rocketeer**, **Laravel**, **Symfony**, **phpseclib** or even **php** itself underneath that needs that many information for establishing a SSH connection?

Comment: I found Rocketeer to be a pain working with. I would rather give you the advise to make a switch to deployer. It's much simpler and has ready-to-go recipes for most frameworks.

Comment: Thank you @NikolaPetkanski for the advice! I actually never used rocketeer because of this issue and switched back to shell scripts. Had my share of Capistrano in between. Today I'm still provisioning and deploying through shell scripts and Ansible. I'll give deployer a try, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Laravel's missing implementation of phpseclib's ssh-agent that requires that many information for establishing a SSH connection.

That's why Rocketeer does not allow to rely on the ssh-agent next to username/password and privatekey/passphrase authentication as does Capistrano.

A proposal was [stated](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4235) and [merged](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4390) to include phpseclib's [undocumented implementation for using the ssh-agent](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent.php) instead of an explicit key.

Rocketeer would profit from this as it relies on said implementation of phpseclib in Laravel.

(Thanks to @hannesvdvreken, @ThomasPayer and @passioncoder for pointing in the right directions)

Answer (score 2):

There are some thing you might want to know.

You can use the default `app/config/remote.php` or you can use the Rocketeer `config.php` that gets published under `app/packages/anahkiasen/rocketeer`.

I tend to use the Laravel file. I made a copy of that file into the `app/config/development` folder which is ignored by git with `.gitignore`. I only write down the passkey of my private key down in that file. It will get merged with the array in `app/config/remote.php`.

Here's my `app/config/development/remote.php` file:

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'staging' => array(
            'keyphrase' => 'your-secret-here',
        ),
        'production' => array(
            'keyphrase' => 'your-secret-here',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response! Though, I already have deployment set up and running with Rocketeer. The question is not how but why the passphrase is needed at all - where's the difference between Capistrano and Rocketeer? I updated my question to clarify this. Writing down the passphrase anywhere is exactly what a I want to avoid ;)

Comment: The passphrase is only needed if your private key is encrypted.

Comment: Exaclty - I do have a passphrase for encrypting my private key which is said to be good practice regarding security. I am able to deploy with capistrano via ssh using an encrypted private key. It does not require to know of the key.

Calling `shell_exec('ssh myserver.com')` in a php script file and executing on cmd gives me results that ensure that a ssh connection was established. I can not believe that phpseclib needs the passphrase either. Has to do with how Laravel handles the connection since Rocketeer just delegates that to Laravel.

Comment: I'm sorry, it does. Running `ssh` on the command line is different than a `phpseclib` session to a server.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to phpseclib. I dug deeper and a colleague actually found phpseclib's undocumented implementation for using the ssh-agent instead of an explicit key: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent.php
But Laravel does not yet offer the option to use it next to username/password and privatekey/passphrase authentication.
I stated a proposal issue here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4235

Rocketeer would definitely profit from this.

Comment: Thank you! :) hopefully we'll have this in the end