# Automated git clone on remote server via ssh, with agent forwarding

Tags: php, git, ssh, phpseclib, ssh-agent

I have a script which uses the ssh agent to login to a remote server. It than tries to clone a private git repository. However, I can't get github to accept the login.

```
<?php
$ssh_agent = new \phpseclib\System\SSH\Agent();
$connection = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2('www.example.com');
$connection->login('example-username', $ssh_agent);

// the clone fails
$commands = array(
    'cd ~/example-path/',
    'ls -la',
    'git clone git@github.com:github-username/repo-name.git'
);
echo $connection->exec(implode('; ', $commands));

// this *does* work
$commands = array(
    'eval $(ssh-agent)',
    'ssh-add ~/.ssh/local-key-copied-on-the-server',
    'cd ~/example-path/',
    'ls -la',
    'git clone git@github.com:github-username/repo-name.git'
);
echo $connection->exec(implode('; ', $commands));
```

The last one *does* work. But it requires me to have the key on the server as well, which I rather would prevent.

When I do this manually, it works.

```
$ ssh -A example-username@www.example.com
$ cd ~/example-path/
$ git clone git@github.com:github-username/repo-name.git
```

It is the forwarding that makes this work, if I skip the `-A`, the clone fails.

In the script, I have verified that:

- the agent (used by the script) holds the key (`ssh-add -l` lists it);
- github accepts cloning the specific repo via a deploy key (which is the key I'm using);
- I'm not logging in with another key, i.e. I've temporarily removed my normal personal key from my github account;

But the script probably doesn't use the forwarding. It is a limitation of phpseclib? Can I set up the local ssh agent in such a way that it uses the forwarding?

Comment: `ssh -A` is the command line equivalent of setting the "ForwardAgent yes" option in ~/.ssh/config.  Have you tried editing the ssh config file?  It may be irrelevant though if phpseclib ignores it.  You might try googling for phpseclib ssh2 with forwardagent and see what turns up.

Comment: A quick search landed here... it might help    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161867/deployment-using-ssh-with-key-without-providing-passphrase-for-private-key-ssh